# Laravel all routes except home page '/' return 404

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

As the title says, all the routes in my laravel app except the home('/') route result in a 404 error.
it works in local server but in production in Ubuntu server return 404.

That is the .htaccess in public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you enabled mod_rewrite on your ubuntu server?

Comment: The Apache Web Server actually

Comment: @stefket yes i did

Comment: Have you checked file permissions on server?